# Spring trace log null ModelAndView returned

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am developing a restful web service using spring boot. I enable spring trace log level and I see the following message:

```
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet : No view rendering, null ModelAndView returned.
```

My controller is like this:

```
@RestController
public class DeliveryMethodController {

    @GetMapping(path = "/my-path", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity getAll(PageableFilter pageableFilter, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
         return new ResponseEntity<>(service.getAll(pageableFilter), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

why this message is generatad? I don't return view at all.

Comment: which is why you get that message it is trace logging to determine what happens if you need to know. As you aren't return a `ModelAndView` the response is directly written to the response instead of a view being rendered.

Comment: Thanks for your response but in @RestController I don't want to return view at all. why the message says "null ModelAndView returned" ?

Comment: Because you aren't returning a `ModelAndView`, the whole MVC infrastructure relies on `ModelAndView` (yes even the JSON and XML under the hood) and this is just a debug message stating that your controller method didn't return a `ModelAndView` and thus the response was written directly. You are seeking too much behind this message it is a **debug** message to see what happens.